# How Textbox interacts with TextElement

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I can write like this

```
<TextBox FontWeight="ExtraBold">                
</TextBox>
```

And I can write like this

```
<TextBox>
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

But i don't understand how TextBox interracts with TExtElement. For example TExtBlock has Inlines property. And MSDN says the following "PasswordBox, RichEditBox and TextBox don't support a text object model that's based on TextElement."
Who knows how it works?!

Answer (score -1):

TextBox.Fontweight inherits from [Control.Fontweight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.fontweight?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Controls_Control_FontWeight), whose Value is of Type [System.Windows.Fontweight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.fontweight?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

[TextElement.FontWeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontweight?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Documents_TextElement_FontWeight) is also of Type [System.Windows.FontWeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.fontweight?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).
You refer to this prop via a Style setter, so you can access the Property over another Class as well (as long the types match)

```
 <TextBox>
      <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="ComboBox.FontWeight"
                  Value="Black" />
        </Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox>
      <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight"
                  Value="Black" />
        </Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Are also valid.

Why this works, see below in Comment.

Comment: "*is also of Type*" is not the reason why the Style works. Just because two properties are of the same type does not mean you can set one by setting the other. The actual reason is `public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(...);` in Control.cs. See the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Control.cs,6750b721a2294fc5).